# Как масштабировать верстку

Tags: css

Есть готовая верстка, width-1920 height-4800 responsiv верстка как в макете. Заказчику не нравится, что на его мониторе все выглядит большим и требует уменьшить ширину до 900 px. Я не особо понимаю как это сделать, без учета того что нужно переделывать всю верстку. Суть вопроса, возможно ли уменьшить масштаб макета без переверстки всего полностью? вот ссылка на сайт http://919970.esy.es/FIDESYS/
Прошу не судить строго т.к. опыта немного.

Comment: Пока что ваш вопрос непонятен. Если уменьшить ширину экрана до 900 пикселей, то страница адаптируется под этот размер. Если же заказчик хочет, чтобы вы сделали центральную колонку с контентом в 900 пкс шириной при любом разрешении, то да, придется переделывать или отстаивать правильность выполненной работы.

Comment: Вам надо переделать дизайн,  уменьшить маштаб не возможно

Comment: У меня есть, картинка pdf с дизайном, 1920х4800 и претензия от стороны заказчика заключалась в том, что у него все элементы большие под его 17д. экран. Можете экспертную оценку сделать по адаптиву правильно ли он масштабируется ?

Comment: Текст и правда большой, тут даже не эксперту понятно )

Comment: Но такие вопросы надо решать апеллируя к утвержденному дизайну, а не к мнению.

Comment: размеры шрифтов действительно большие. уменьшите их, это же несложно. хочет по бокам пустые поля - ну сделайте (как это сделано на данном сайте). если не получается, задайте более частный вопрос по верстке (приведя пример своей верстки и как хотите ее изменить).